# sh file is not running on slave node in jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, remote-access, master-slave

Hi I am fairly new to jenkins config and I am struck on running sh file on slave node. I have created two jobs one is creating some .sh and .jar file and other is copying it to all the slave node, after the build I need to run the .sh file which is running on local but not running on master. I am specifying the path but Jenkins is always running some blank .sh file from tmp folder.

[image]
where as in job config I have given this
[image]
the slave.sh file is present on remote slave but jenkins is not running it, what is the possible cause?

Comment: What is that? Pardon me for asking. In the master node I have provided the same config and master.sh is running but when I am trying it for remote it is not...

Comment: But why  jenkins is executing some other .sh file and not the specified one.

Answer (score -1):

I really do not understand what you are trying to do. You have a very strange way to dividing the work and then executing part of it in a post-build step. There should be very few use-cases for using post-build step. Maybe you could just try to execute the slave.sh script in a normal build step? And maybe execute it directly from the source location without copying it to another location.

If I'm missing something and it really is necessary to execute slave.sh in a post-build step, please verify the path to the script is correct. There are several similar but slightly different paths in your question and I cannot say if that is on purpose but probably not.